# Getting node in theme_preprocess_node

Tags: 8, nodes, i18n-l10n

I have this code:

```
function material_base_preprocess_node(&$variables){
    $node = $variables['node'];
    $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
    $variables['username'] = $node->getOwner()->getTranslation($language)->field_name->value;
    $variables['mediums1'] = $node->getTranslation($language)->field_mediums->value;
}
```

this line works fine:

```
 $variables['username'] = $node->getOwner()->getTranslation($language)->field_name->value;
```

but this

```
 $variables['mediums1'] = $node->getTranslation($language)->field_mediums->value;
```

gets error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</br></br><em class="placeholder">InvalidArgumentException</em>: Invalid translation language (en) specified. in <em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase-&gt;getTranslation()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">789</em> of <em class="placeholder">core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php</em>).
```

Why this code works for user, but not for node and how to fix that?

this one works

```
$node->get('field_mediums')->entity->getTranslation($language)->name->value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception message says, there is no english translation for that node.

The node is already in the translation that Drupal determined is the best available translation for this page.

If you do want to get a specific translation, you need to check with `hasTranslation()` first or use `\Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($entity, $langcode);`

Comment: Ok, but I have translated taxonomy in non-translated node. Can I get this even if node isn't translated?

Comment: Sure, but you tried to get the node, not the taxonomy term. That call above works on any entity type, just get the entity with $node->get('your_taxonomy_field')->entity and then pass that to getTranslationFromContext()

Comment: Try this one:  `$variables['mediums1'] =$node->get('field_mediums')->entity->getTranslation($language)->value;` but nothing is printed.

Comment: That is not what I said how you should use getTranslationFromContext(). *not* getTranslation(). When you have the term you need to access its fields, there is no value field. So label() or ->name->value for example